# UnicodeError Reading Accentuation Portuguese Characters from File

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

**Preface:**

It's a cold, rainy day, in mid 2016, and a developer is still having encode issues with python for not using Python 3.0. Will the great S.O community help him ? I don't know, we will have to wait and see

**Scope:**

I have a `UTF-8` [encoded file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/CodeToShare/keywords_used.txt) that contains words with accentuation, such as `CURRÍCULO` and `NÓS`. For some reason I can't grasp, I can't manage to read them properly using Python 2.7.

**Code Snippet:**

```
import codecs

f_reader = codecs.open('PATH_TO_FILE/Data/Input/kw.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')

for line in f_reader:
    keywords.append(line.strip().upper())
    print line
```

The output I get is:

```
TRABALHE CONOSCO
ENVIE SEU CURRICULO
ENVIE SEU CURRÍCULO  
UnicodeEncodeError, 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xcd' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Encoding, Encoding, Encoding:**

I have used notepad++ to convert the file to both regular utf-8 and the one without the ByteOrderMark, and it shows me the characters just fine, without any issue. I'm using Windows, by the way, which will create files as ANSI by default.

**Question:**

What should I do to be able to read this file properly, including the `í` and `ó` and other accentuated characters ?

Just to make it clearer, I want to `keep the accentuation` on the strings I use in memory.

**Update:**

Here's the List of Keywords, in memory, read from the file using the code you can see.

[image: List of Keywords as read in memory]

Comment: They're reading just fine. Read the full traceback.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Can you define "just fine" ? The program crashes when trying to encode it to the same encode that the file is in, in theory. What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you read the traceback yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You mean, that the "print" printed it just fine. Is it what you mean ? Yes, I've read that. What I can't grasp is why it crashes on this very line, right after the print method is invoked. It prints and crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems not to be in the reading, but in the printing. You sad

> I'm using Windows, by the way, which will create files as ANSI by default.

I think that includes printing to `stdout`. Try change the `sys.output` codec:

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Here is part of the list of keywords printed, using the 'print' method, after overriding the sys.stdout with the codecs one:

[u'TRABALHE CONOSCO', u'ENVIE SEU CURRICULO', u'ENVIE SEU CURR\xcdCULO', u'MANDE SEU CURR\xcdCULO']

Comment: It's right. This is the printing using `repr` for each element of the list. Try printing `u", ".join(keywords)` for example. Or print each line to a file and open the file to check the encoding.

Comment: u','.join(keywords) gives me `ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)` error.

Any clues ?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this error. Is the error on `join` or  `print`? Try create a intermediary variable: `x = u", ".join(keywords)`; `print x` to see.

Comment: Note that you cannot mix "normal string" with unicode strings (prefix `u`). Maybe you should put `u` prefix in the appropriated strings in your code.